# Apache nutch and solr : queries

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

I have just started using **Nutch** 1.9 and **Solr** 4.10

After browsing through certain pages I see that syntax for running this version has been changed, and I have to update certain xml's for configuring **Nutch** and **Solr**

This version of package doesnt require Tomcat for running. I started **Solr**:

*java -jar start.jar*

and checked *localhost:8983/solr/admin*, its working.

I planted a seed in *bin/url/seed.txt* and seed is "simpleweb.org"

Ran **Command** in Nutch: `./crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5`

I got few IO exceptions in the middle and so to avoid the IO exception I downloaded
*patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win.jar* and made an entry in *nutch-site.xml* and placed the jar file in lib of **Nutch**.

After running **Nutch**,
Following folders were created:

```
apache-nutch-1.9\bin\-dir\crawldb\current\part-00000
```

I can see following files in that path:

```
data<br>
index<br>
.data.crc<br>
.index.crc<br>
```

I want to know what to do with these files, what are the next steps? Can we view these files? If yes, how?

I indexed the crawled data from **Nutch** into **Solr**:

for linking solr with nutch (command completed successfully)
**Command** *./crawl urls solr http://localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 3 -topN 5*

Why do we need to index the data crawled by **Nutch** into **Solr**?

After crawling using **Nutch**

command used for this: `./crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5;` can we view the crawled data, if yes, where?

**OR** only after indexing the data crawled by **Nutch** into **Solr**, can we view the crawled data entires?

How to view the crawled data in Solr web?

command used for this: `./crawl urls solr localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 3 -topN 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Nutch was built to be a web scale search engine, this is not the case any more. Currently, the main purpose of Nutch is to do a large scale crawling. What you do with that crawled data is then up to your requirements. By default, Nutch allows to send data into Solr. That is why you can run

```
crawl url crawl solraddress depth level
```

You can emit the solr url parameter also. In that case, nutch will not send the crawled data into Solr. Without sending the crawled data to solr, you will not be able to search data. Crawling data and searching data are two different things but very related.

Generally, you will find the crawled data in the crawl/segments not crawl/crawdb. The crawl db folder stores information about the crawled urls, their fetching status and next time for fetching plus some other useful information for crawling. Nutch stores actual crawled data in crawl/segments.

If you want to have an easy way to view crawled data, you might try nutch 2.x as it can store its crawled data into several back ends like MySQL, Hbase, Cassandra and etc through the Gora component.

To view data at solr, you simplly issue a query to Solr like this:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/select/?q=*:*
```

Otherwise, you can always push your data into different stores via adding indexer plugins. Currently, Nutch supports sending data to Solr and Elasticsearch. These indexer plugins send structured data like title, text, metadata, author and other metadata.

The following summarizes what happens in Nutch:

```
seed list -> crawldb -> fetching raw data (download site contents) 
-> parsing the raw data -> structuring the parse data into fields (title, text, anchor text, metadata and so on)-> 
sending the structured data to storage for usage (like ElasticSearch and Solr).
```

Each of these stages is extendable and allows you to add your logic to suit your requirements.

I hope that clears your confusion.

Comment: thanks for the reply. iam working on nutch1.9 using cygwin in windows. crawl/segments is not getting created for me. Only crawl/crawdb is getting created.And when i run the command ` ./crawl urls -crawl -depth 3 -topN 5` am getting following error. how to resolve!!!
Fetcher: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/cygwin64/home/apache-nutch-1.9-bin/apache-nutch-1.9/bin/-crawl/segments/crawl_generate

Comment: can you recommend a valid tutorial for setting up nutch in windows. am frustrated on this

Comment: i honestly will not recommend running Nutch in windows. It is just unpredictable. Try to run in virtual machine.

Comment: am using cygwin..isnt it same as unix environment..so the steps i have to follow must be same as unix env.. right..

Comment: Nutch uses hadoop and  hadoop does not work that well in cygwin. I have not used Nutch in cygwin, so I can not help much here. Btw, can you accept the answer if it solves your original question.

Comment: so, if i follow the same procedure in, lets say ubuntu 12.4, it wud be working fine?..sry for being naive, just started drilling down from the base

Comment: Yes, it should work fine. In fact, ubutnu is the right choice if you want to switch to pseudo  cluster mode.

Answer (score 0):

u can run nutch on windows-I am also a beginner-yes it is a bit tough to install in windows but it do works!-this input path doesn't exist problem can be solved by:-
replacing Hadoop-core-1.2.0.jar file in apache-nutch-1.9/lib with hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar(from maven)
then rename this new file as hadoop-core-1.2.0